# Can't make two routes with implicit binding on same url in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, binding, routes, implicit

I have two routes with parameters

First one looks like this:

```
Route::get('/{subject}',[
    'as' => 'cheatsheet.subjects', 'uses' => 'CheatsheetController@subjects'
]);
```

Second one like this

```
Route::get('/{cheatsheet}',[
    'as' => 'cheatsheet.detail', 'uses' => 'CheatsheetController@detail'
]);
```

This throws error:

No query results for model [App\Models\Subject].

If I type the second route like this

```
Route::get('/{subject}/{cheatsheet}',[
    'as' => 'cheatsheet.detail', 'uses' => 'CheatsheetController@detail'
]);
```

It works, but the problem is that i am recreating website with a unlogical urls, and i need to make the urls same because of SEO, so this is not solution.

I think that this error is occuring because even thouhg a reference routes with route names, it checks for url and it takes the first one which is incorrect.

Could you please have any suggestion how to fix this or tell me where i am wrong? Thank you very much.

Comment: You will have one route, and then in the controller check if it is a subject or a cheatsheet.

Comment: To add to @NicklasKevinFrank 's comment, you could use a polymorphic relation and use that to check if it is a subject or cheatsheet